# Is it important to remember port order when replacing RAID disks?

Tags: raid

I've been running 4 Seagate 160GB HDD's in Raid 1/0 for about 4 years now. I've since purchased 4 VelociRaptors to replace those disks.

I'm planning on pulling the disks out and putting them aside for safe keeping (in case I've missed anything in my backup), but I'm wondering if I need to have a solid record of what SATA port they were attached to in my Raid config.

I've got a Highpoint RocketRaid 4 port controller.

Comment: This is a good question.  I've never thought of it.  I assume there is some metadata on the disks that indicates what part they play in an array, but I have no information to back up that hunch.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Disk order *can* be important, but just as often the controller has some firmware to sort out the order based on disk metadata. Because of this it's unlikely that ordering information will be strictly *needed* for the data to be recovered, and it should *always* be possible to retrieve that information from the disks themselves at a later date if ordering is important.

None the less, the more you can document, the better, so I'd write down the port each disk is on even if it doesn't matter at all.

Comment: Thanks for this. I ended up running a "test" whereby I left the disks in the machine but just swapped the cables around (documenting the original location), and then fired it back up. It showed the disk without missing a beat!